# QT Creator - Centering elements(gridLayout) within stackedWidget page

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt6

MainWindow -> centralWidget -> stackedWidget -> page_startScreen -> gridLayout_StartScreen -> (page elements go in here)

I have learned how to center elements in QT Creator using layouts and spacers, but when trying to do the same inside of a stackedWidget page, I can't. I put in a gridLayout for centering, but the gridLayout itself does not dynamically take all available room. It won't change with window resizing.

[Screenshot from the QT Creator project of the Form and the object tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7v3h.png)

I'm surprised I can't find this information online. If you found it online, please tell me how so I can see what I did wrong.

Comment: Your `page_startScreen` widget has no layout. You have put a QGridLayout inside it, but it's not assigned to a widget.

Comment: So the same way I made centralwidget have a grid layout, I can do the exact same to the pages. I incorrectly assumed that was only possible at the top level. Thank you.